# Does blackbox exporter support telnet probe?

Tags: docker, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

Does blackbox exporter support telnet probe? I cannot see this in the blackbox example config file in [blackbox.yml](https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter/blob/master/example.yml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, the prometheus blackbox exporter support telnet this way

```
tcp_connect_example:
    prober: tcp
    timeout: 5s
```

Every tcp probe is a telnet probe.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [Blackbox exporter](https://kubefront.com/linux/how-to-install-and-configure-blackbox-exporter-for-prometheus) supports TCP module you can tell black box in its blackbox.yml config file like this.

```
tcp_connect:
    prober: tcp
    timeout: 5s
```

for testing just run

```
curl 'http://localhost:9115/probe?target=10.20.10.10:22&module=tcp_connect&debut=true'
```